# How can I map the result set of query to a different entity other than table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to fetch data from db and mapping it to different entity but I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

My Table looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "findAll", query = "Select a.student_id as id, a.student_code as code from Student a")
    })
public class Student {

    @Id
    private Long student_id;
    private String student_code;
    private String student_user_id;
    private String student_first_name;

    //Some other fields, getters and setters
}
```

My BO Looks like

```
@Entity
public class Generic{

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private String user_id;

    //getters and setters
}
```

My DAO call class something like this

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findAll", Generic.class);
query.getResultList();
```

I get exception on

```
entityManager.createNamedQuery("findAll", Generic.class);
```

This is the stack trace I have

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.buildQueryFromName(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:774)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:869)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createNamedQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:301)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy157.createNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you please brief the exception trace for this, do you have constructor in pojo class which accept these two varaibles a.student_id as id, a.student_code

Comment: which `hibernate-orm` version you are using?

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to fetch data from db and mapping it to a different entity
>   but I get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

But in the following line, you are not doing that, you are trying to get the list of `Student` entity list. And what's your different Entity here?

`entityManager.createNamedQuery("findAll", Student.class);`

But as you provided another entity `Generic`, I assume you want your data to be loaded in that. There are different possible solutions to this problem. Lets figure out.

### Using the **SELECT NEW** keywords

Update your Native query to this

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Student.findAll", query = "SELECT NEW Generic(a.student_id, a.student_code) FROM Student a")
})
```

You have to define a Constructor in the `Generic` class as well that qualifies this call

```
public void Generic(Long id, String code) {
     this.id = id;
     this.code = code;
}
```

And update the query execution in DAO as

```
List<Generic> results = em.createNamedQuery("Student.findAll" , Generic.class).getResultList();
```

*Note:* *You may have to place the fully qualified path for the `Generic` class in the Query for this*

### Construct from `List<Object[]>`

Alternatively the straight forward and simplest solution would fetch the result list as a list of `Object[]` and populate to any new Object you want.

```
List<Object[]> list = em.createQuery("SELECT s.student_id, s.student_code FROM Student s")
                        .getResultList(); 

for (Object[] obj : list){
    Generic generic = new Generic();
    generic.setId(((BigDecimal)obj[0]).longValue());
    generic.setCode((String)obj[1]);
}
```

Comment: I did try this one. but i get exception saying that Student.student_id is BigDecimal and Generic.id is long. Can I do type casting anyway without changing the data types?

Comment: you need to cast it as `BigDecimal` actually. See the updated answer

Comment: Is there a way I can do directly in the Named native query, I am avoiding to use objects

Comment: Did you try the `SELECT NEW` approach?